# Removing tags inside a string with strip?

Tags: python, split, strip

Is there anyway to remove characters inside a string using strip? For example

If i take:

```
s = <city>Omaha</city>
s.strip("< ").strip(" > \n").strip("/")
```

That would turn into:

```
city>Omaha</city
```

Is there anyway to remove the city> and < / city using strip or split?

Comment: Please finish your question. Do you want to know how to remove anything that is inside angle brackets, such as `<city>` and `</city>`? Or just ones at the start or end of the string?

Comment: Sorry, it got cut off. I Just fixed it

Comment: You only partially answered my question. In another comment you say you do not want just `<city>`. Do you want to remove all angle brackets? Only ones paired with a slash in the second? Only at the start and end or also inside the string?

Comment: `str.strip` removes only leading or trailing characters. You may need to consider `str.replace` instead.

Comment: Does it have to only be strip or split? Not good enough if the tags are just removed with some other method?

Comment: It's supposed to be Strip or Split

Answer (score 0):

If the brackets are always `<city>` and `</city>`:

```
>>> s = "<city>Omaha</city>"
>>> s.strip("<city>").strip("</city>")
'Omaha'
```

Comment: That would work but not all the data is <city>. there is <name>, <age>, etc

Comment: @JohnDoe do you know if it is a valid file type, e.g. xml?

Answer (score 0):

This code removes all properly nested tags by splitting:

```
s = "In the <noun>city</noun> of <city>Omaha</city>..."
parts = [x.split(">") for x in s.split("<")]
print(parts)
# [['In the '], ['noun', 'city'], ['/noun', ' of '], ['city', 'Omaha'], ['/city', '...']]
s = ''.join(parts[0] + [part[1] for part in parts[1:]])
print(s)
# In the city of Omaha...
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by your example specifically - If there won't be 2 tagged words in the input:

```
s = "<city>Omaha</city>"
s.split('>')[1].split('<')[0]
```

outputs:

```
'Omaha'
```

That'll work even if there is a full sentence - provided there is only 1 tag in the sentence.

If there can be more than one:

```
example = "An example is only <word>valid</word> when its not <opposite>invalid</opposite>."
split_example = example.split('>')
for i in range(len(split_example)):
    if "</" in split_example[i]:
        split_example[i].split('<')[0]
```

outputs:

```
'valid'
'invalid'
```